# Open default launcher intent

Tags: android, android-intent, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to set my app as the default launcher. It works with other devices, but I am having issues with Huawei. It seems like Huawei doesn't follow the standards (once again). This is the code I use:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName mockupComponent = new  ComponentName(MockupLauncher.class.getPackage().getName(), MockupLauncher.class.getName());

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(mockupComponent,  PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(mockupComponent, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I copied that code long time ago from another great stackoverflow answer.
As I said, it is not working for Huawei devices. It just displays nothing. So, is there a way to open the intent to **let the user manually** select the Home launcher for Huawei devices. These are the screenshots I have in the Huawei:

[image]

So, I would like to be able to open the 3rd screenshot, or the 2nd. Is it possible?